# How to implement a cache system using Celery and Flask

Tags: python, caching, flask, redis, celery

I am implementing an online server using:

- `Flask`
- `NGINX`
- `Celery`

Celery uses:

- `RabbitMQ` as a broker
- `Redis` as a Result backend.

I would like to know if it is possible to use `Redis` as a cache to avoid doing big calculations if I receive the same request. For example, I want to answer a cache result if I receive a `POST` containing the same body.

If it is possible, do I have to configure it in Celery or in Redis? And how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many existing extensions in the flask eco-system that let you do this easily. Including [Flask-Redis](https://github.com/underyx/flask-redis)